# How to minimize the maximum of $n$ multivariate functions?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If I have $n$ functions $f_i:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. What approach should I take to minimize $max(f_i)$?

For example, Consider:

$$f_1(l_1,l_2)=l_1+l_2$$

$$f_2(l_1, l_2)=x_2-l_2+l_1$$

$$f_3(l_1, l_2)=x_1-l_1+l_2$$

$$f_4(l_1, l_2)=x_1+x_2+l_1+l_2$$

for some constants $x_1, x_2$. I want to minimize $max((f_1,f_2,f_3, f_4)(l_1,l_2))$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{N}$? Natural numbers?

Comment: @Ture Yes, the naturals. Including zero.

Comment: @AspiringMat Perhaps I am misunderstanding your notation, but isn't the maximum of all these functions you've defined $\infty$? Both sums and differences can be arbitrarily big given natural numbers for operands, even if shifted by a constant.

Comment: @WB-man Yes, but I want to minimize the maximum. Meaning even though they all can range to infinity, I want the minimum value of the maximum of all 4 as $l_1$ and $l_2$ varies.

Comment: @AspiringMat Okay. That's what I thought you meant. But in that case, since the maximum of all four of your functions is $\infty$, wouldn't the minimum over the maximums of all four functions then simply $\infty$ as well? This feels too simple an answer to be what you're looking for, so that's why I ask.

Comment: @WB-man Yes, but what I mean is the minimum while varying $l_1$ and $l_2$. Not the minimum of each maximum individually. In other words, $l_1, l_2$ are varying on $NxN$ and I am evaluating the 4 functions at each of the points and taking the maximum. Now what I need is the **minimum** of all these maximums at different points.

Comment: @AspiringMat I think I see now. Do you mean something like this? $$\min_{l_1, l_2} \Big(\max\big\{f_1(l_1,l_2),\ f_2(l_1,l_2),\ \text{etc.} \big\} \Big)$$

Comment: @WB-man Exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can try to solve the following problem:
$$
\underset{l_1\in \mathbb{N},l_2\in \mathbb{N},t}{\text{mininize}}\quad t\\
\text{subject to} \quad f_1(l_1,l_2)\leq t\\
\quad \quad \quad \quad f_2(l_1,l_2)\leq t\\
\quad \quad \quad \quad f_3(l_1,l_2)\leq t\\
\quad \quad \quad \quad f_4(l_1,l_2)\leq t
$$

Comment: I am not sure how I would go ahead with that? Is this a known form? Least-squares perhaps?

Comment: This is an integer linear programming problem. I just gave you a proper way of writing the optimization problem. Now the big problem is that you have restricted the variables to be integers (otherwise you could use the simplex method to solve this problem). Are you using Matlab? Then this might be useful https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html

Comment: So I take it that there is likely no analytical way to do it (Only approximation)?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, sorry. Do you use Matlab? Otherwise, I can continue to search for nice algorithms.

Comment: I do use Matlab. I have actually approximated the answer, however I was hoping for an elegant analytical way. Thanks regardless!

Comment: Sure! Good luck with your problem! :)